# Ip redirect with same DNS name

Tags: redirect, amazon-ec2, dns, ip

I am trying to do disaster recovery of my physical servers. I wan to redirect the ip to AWS EC2 instance in case of disaster. But I want my DNS name to be same and ip redirection to be smooth without much downtime.

Please suggest my suitable ways that myweb.com should remain same and I am redirected to AWS server.

Answer (score 0):

Set a short [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) for your A and AAAA records in DNS.

Then if you need to redirect to your DR servers, then the propagation time will be minimised.

Comment: How can I redirect to ip on AWS? If I do not wish to use Elastic ip services from AWS.

Comment: Fire up your instance, EC2 dashboard will show you the public DNS name and IP, then simply set your DNS A record or CNAME to the public IP or hostname respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can detach that Elastic IP and attache same to another EC2 instance.

If you want this to be dynamic you need to use AWS CLI.

Thanks - Kunal Shah

Comment: Can you show with an example on AWS CLI? through commands or so.